# Why are visa application centres called "visa sections"?

Tags: etymology

In [this article](http://www.migrationwatchuk.org/key-topics/international-students), the term "visa sections" is used to refer seemingly to visa application centres, in the following passage:

> Applications around the world soared and visa sections in parts of India, China, Bangladesh and Nepal were closed to new applicants for many months amid concerns over fraudulent applications.

Then, I encountered the term in the photo in [this blog article](http://flashpackatforty.com/2016/05/07/what-your-country-can-do-for-you-justfly-tells-you-what-your-embassy-can-do-for-you/).

How did this term come to be used for visa application centres?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it originally referred to **the Visa section of the embassy** - eg the British embassy in Moscow might have a "Visa section", where they just deal with visa applications.

This term may have expanded out to apply to other offices which deal with visas, even if they're not physically located in the embassy.  It may even be valid in that case, if it's seen as a section of the government, aka a **department**:  eg "The government has visa sections located in the following cities:"

Eg here's the Belarusian embassy's Visa Section page - http://uk.mfa.gov.by/en/consular_issues/